# Active menu link should "crop" the menu strip?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have a strange menu to code and I have no idea how to do it, i have this 100% wide header strip, on the left side the logo sits and on the right the menu. The strip goes over fullscreen background. So, i need the active link to somehow crop the header strip, like make a hole. I attached an image so you can get a better idea. Thanks !

Here is the image:

http://oi49.tinypic.com/166zvo0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use background opacity

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
background:url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C4Py3QDewmA/Td8HQzGhbcI/AAAAAAAAALU/BeVowacOJiA/s320/brick_wall.jpg) left top 
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
   background: rgba(255,255,255,0.60);
}
li:hover{
    background:none
}
a{
    color:white; font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aALbE/22/)**